# SQL Update - How to add an additional int to a list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have look through all of the boards and googled but just have not found a solution.

I am trying to update a number of records that have a list of integers: 43,23,756,21

And then taking the list and adding 45 to the end of it. So it will be 43,23,756,21,45.

Here is is the statement:

```
UPDATE ACCOUNT_GROUPS
SET groups = groups + N',' + '#URL.group_id#'
WHERE account_id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#session.account_id#" />
  AND admin_user = '1'
  AND admin_update_code = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_char" value="#form.admin_update_code#" null="#form.admin_update_code eq ''#"/>
```

I tried:

```
UPDATE ACCOUNT_GROUPS
SET groups = CAST(groups AS varchar) + ',' + #URL.group_id# 
WHERE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#session.account_id#" />
  AND admin_user = '1'
  AND admin_update_code = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_char" value="#form.admin_update_code#" null="#form.admin_update_code eq ''#"/>

UPDATE ACCOUNT_GROUPS
SET groups = CONCAT(groups, ','@newID)  
WHERE account_id = '#session.account_id#'
  AND admin_user = '1'
  AND admin_update_code = '#form.admin_update_code#'
```

Groups is the list and URL.group_id is the new var that we'd like to add on.

I tried `CONCAT` and a few other functions as you can see above but just not working correctly.

Can anyone help?

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: What about this isn't working correctly? Are yuo getting errors? Unexpected results? Something else?

Comment: Thanks for responding.... Each one of them did not like the syntax. I know I'm close one at least one of them but it's just not formed correctly.

Comment: It would be great if SQL had a ListAppend function....

Comment: No it wouldn't. You are not *supposed* to store multiple values in a single column, instead store them in separate rows normalized into another table. You also have some serious SQL injection issues going on there. Be that as it may, `SET groups = CONCAT(groups, ',', @newID)` should work. Otherwise please construct a [mcve], maybe using https://dbfiddle.uk

Comment: Thanks so much...I swear I tried that but here is the error I get back: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'AND'.

Comment: Actually I played around with it and eventually worked. Thank you so much your help. For those who might have the same problem/questions, here it is the finished query that worked:

Comment: UPDATE ACCOUNT_GROUPS
            SET groups = CONCAT(groups, ',', #form.group_id#) 
            WHERE account_id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#session.account_id#" />
            AND admin_user = '1'
            AND admin_update_code = '#form.admin_update_code#'

Comment: Many databases do have an array type and json type where you can work with more unstructured data like this natively. SQL Server isn't one of the though (at least to my knowledge). That being said, I would agree with @Charlieface that if the data structure is known, it's best to implement the proper table schema to store it, and it's never a good idea to store multiple values in a non-multi-value type like varchar. It will lead very slow and very complex sql.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I played around with it and eventually worked. Thank you so much your help. For those who might have the same problem/questions, here it is the finished query that worked:

```
UPDATE ACCOUNT_GROUPS 
SET groups = CONCAT(groups, ',', #form.group_id#) 
WHERE account_id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#session.account_id#" /> 
AND admin_user = '1' 
AND admin_update_code = '#form.admin_update_code#'
```

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working!

Comment: Like I said, there is a huge SQL injection problem there, which you really need to sort out, to say nothing of the normalization issues with storing multiple values in a single column.